# TinyMCE Cloud - Allow adding css?

Tags: tinymce

Is there any way to allow TinyMCE to let our users to add their own styles?  Either linking to the CSS or adding it between  tags

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE has two options to inject CSS:

`content_css` - https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/add-css-options/#content_css

`content_style` - https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/add-css-options/#content_style

These are both added to the configuration you use to `init()` TinyMCE.

Comment: This would be ok if we added in the backend.  What Im looking for is a way to allow users to add it in the editor.  Open the source code put in style tags or link rel   When we do this these elements were striped out when saved